# Elastic Search Query builder

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elastic search json response like:

```
"source": {
lastupdate_es: "2016-01-11T11:22:49.800Z",
prod_id: [
"prod12345"
],
price: [
{
price_list: "ADomain",
list_price: 31.67
},
{
price_list: "ADomain",
list_price: 760
},
{
price_list: "ADomain",
list_price: 31.67
},
{
price_list: "BDomain",
list_price: 760
},
{
price_list: "BDomain",
list_price: 29.66
},
{
price_list: "CDomain",
list_price: 710
},

],
sku_id: "sku123445"
}
```

I need a query to filter records, the SQL query would be something like "select * from table where prop_id='product id' and price_list like '%Domain'. How can we create an elastic query to achieve this?

Comment: I would rather write the query filter not the result filter. If you post your query maybe I can help with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you like SQL syntax, [that](https://github.com/NLPchina/elasticsearch-sql) may be a solution for you.

Use something like this

```
POST /index_name/table/_search

{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "prod_id": "prod12345"
          },
          "regexp": {
            "price_list": ".Domain"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

to perform your query in elasticsearch directly.